# Unable to add Face Cognitive Service Nuget

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to integrate `Microsoft Cognitive Service Face API` in my `Xamarin Forms` app. I have installed the `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.DotNetStandard Version="1.0.0"` , `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face" Version="1.4.0"` in my PCL. But every time I try to compile my code I get an error

For iOS I get:

```
xxx.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.IFaceServiceClient" reference from "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" (MT2002)
```

For Android I get :

```
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
    File name: 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.dll'
      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) [0x0009a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5945/dffc5912/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:229 
      at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5945/dffc5912/source/monodroid/external/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:179 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T] assemblies, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, System.Boolean topLevel) [0x0014a] in <96027da06dd5411688a31011072e256f>:0 
      at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAs

semblyResolver resolver) [0x00237] in <96027da06dd5411688a31011072e256f>:0
```

Xamarin Forms : 3.0.0.482510.
Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem right here:

> I have installed the Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common.**DotNetStandard**
>   Version="1.0.0", Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face" Version="1.4.0" in my
>   **PCL**

You are trying to install a .NET Standard library into your PCL which are not guaranteed to be compatible. You either want to upgrade your PCL to a .NET Standard library (which is a good idea no matter what) or install an older version of the NuGet package.